# API call is taking too long to respond. How can I pass the control from this function and come back again later

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, google-hangouts

I am creating a chatbot in python flask web server. I have this function that sends query to api and responds back on to the chatbot.

```
     def generateresponse(command):
       #do something
       text = runapi(uri) 
       return text

    def runapi(uri):
       r = requests.get(uri, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
       parsed = js.loads(r.text,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
       return parsed

   def on_event():
       event = request.get_json()  #receives an event from the chatbot
       #do something
       resp = generateresponse(event)
       apiasyncresp(resp, spaceName)
       return json.jsonify()
```

This runapi method calls a mulesoft api to return the result. However it is taking longer to respond for some of the queries. I want to return a text - "waiting for response" back to the chatbot(if i don't get any response from runapi() in 30 seconds) and keep executing runapi till it returns an output. How can I do so?
I don't want to stop the response from coming in. I only want that before 30 seconds generateresponse() can return 'waiting' message without pausing the execution of runapi()

Answer (score 0):

**As my knowledge**, you can invoke a function after some point of time using [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)

See this example:

```
from threading import Timer

set_time = 1
event = Timer(set_time, hello)

def message():
    t.cancel()
    return "Waiting for the response"

def api():
    event.start()
    r = requests.get("http://www.satp.org/Timelines.aspx?countries=bangladesh")
    t.cancel()
    print("finish")
    return r

api()
```

But, you can't return some initial message first and then once you get response returning output is not possible.

Comment: I don't want to stop the response from coming in. I only want that before 30 seconds generateresponse() can return 'waiting' message without pausing the execution of runapi().

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you send a *synchronous* response from your bot via `generateresponse()` with the "waiting for response" message. You can create a thread as [Narendra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647038/narendra-prasath) suggested to run `runapi()` so that when it returns, it sends an *asynchronous* msg to the chat room with the desired results. See [this Flask async example from Google](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/hangouts-chat-samples/tree/master/python/basic-async-bot) on GitHub -- it doesn't have threading but does show you how to (use a service account to) post an asynchronous msg into a chat room.